# cp Cannot Stat '-r'

Tags: command-line, cp

Strange issue, for some reason, when I'm running a copy command, it's treating the -r flag as an argument.

```
sudo cp –r usr/* /usr
```

The following is the error:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘–r’: No such file or directory
```

I know that -r doesn't exist as a file/directory, that's because it's a flag of to cp command, not an argument.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: So how to I ensure I'm always typing the correct one? My keyboard only has the one variation of it, and I'm sure I've never had this issue before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the comments, it looks like you've copied a long-dash (`&ndash;`). This is syntactically different to a regular dash and the `cp` command is just reading it like it's a filename.

Endashes are *slightly but noticeably* longer than regular dashes. There's an even longer version called an emdash. Here's a comparison between the three:

```
- dash
– endash
— emdash
```

If you've copied this organically from a web page, this might explain it. Wordpress substitutes a double dash for an emdash and I'm sure there's a wierd substitution for an endash too.

To type this manually, most users need to use the compose key combo: <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

If your keyboard is generating these on its own, there's something odd going on in your keymap. Longer dashes aren't —as far as I know— standard base punctuation for any language.

Comment: You are correct, I copied this from a web-page. And I retyped it myself and it was fine.